# Cannot be used as an extractor in a pattern because it lacks an unapply or unapplySeq method

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have a quite simple Scala code where I wanted to apply pattern matching:

```
trait Expr
case class Number(n: Int) extends Expr
case class Sum(a: Expr, b: Expr) extends Expr
case class Prod(a: Expr, b: Expr) extends Expr

def eval(e: Expr): Int = e match
  case Number(n) => n
  case Sum(a, b) => eval(a) + eval(b)
  case Prod(a, b) => eval(a) * eval(b)
```

But when I run the code the error rises: "Number cannot be used as an extractor in a pattern because it lacks an unapply or unapplySeq method"

What should I do to avoid this error?
Thank you

Comment: I can't reproduce it: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/N2TIb2xXQZC48wDgAYSqkA/1 So it is either an IDE error _(that seems **Scala 3**, and maybe you are using **IntelliJ** and it doesn't support it well yet)_  or you have more code to show to be able to reproduce the error - BTW, if you are using **Scala 3**, you may want to use an `enum` instead.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I suppose you're right, I was using IntelliJ, and in VS Code it works well.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have imported `java.lang.Number` in the scope of the `eval` definition.

Make sure to import your `Number` definition instead (either by removing the Java import or renaming it, whatever fits best your use case...) and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's true what was said before, that `java.lang.Number` shadows `case class Number` when run in IntelliJ. If you don't want to abandon your IDE, you can also rename `case class Number` to `case class Num`. This way, the code runs fine at least on my machine.